# how to print out the data from stored procedure in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

As my assignment needs me to use stored procedure, i wanted to print out the data in the table, but it only shows (PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.) but none of the data print out.Below is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE showMenu(Merchant_N IN Varchar2)
AS 
Food_Name Varchar2(30) := null;
BEGIN
SELECT Food_Name 
INTO Food_Name
From Food , Merchant
Where Merchant_Name = Merchant_N AND 
Merchant.Merchant_ID = Food.Merchant_ID;
dbms_output.enable; 
dbms_output.put_line('The food is');
dbms_output.put_line(Food_Name);
END;

EXEC showMenu(‘KFC’)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question - processing multiple rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE showMenu(Merchant_N IN Varchar2)
AS 
Food_Name Varchar2(30) := null;
BEGIN
  for x in (SELECT Food_Name 
            -- INTO Food_Name   not needed for cursor loops
            From Food , Merchant
            Where Merchant_Name = Merchant_N AND 
           Merchant.Merchant_ID = Food.Merchant_ID)
  loop
    --  dbms_output.enable; < not needed
    dbms_output.put_line('The food is');
    dbms_output.put_line(x.Food_Name);  --
  end loop;
END;
```

Do you really want two lines each?  How about

```
loop
        dbms_output.put_line('The food is '|| x.Food_Name);
end loop;
```

And you really should use ANSI join syntax:

```
From Food  
     join Merchant on Food.Merchant_ID = Merchant.Merchant_ID
Where Merchant_Name = Merchant_N
```

Comment: oh it works! thank you very much , it helps a lot ! been trying for few hours already.

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on
```

set the serveroutput to on then execute the proc again then you should see an output

Comment: May i ask another question, for example if KFC have 2 food in my table , it will occurs error,what should i do to enable the program to print out the data >1

Comment: can you elaborate I am not sure I am understanding the question

Comment: @CHANWILSON you just need to add exception handling. Before the end of the procedure, add `EXCEPTION WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN` and after that put whatever exception handling code you want.

Comment: for example, my kfc got 2 food, i need to print out the 2 food but these code only print out the first food and cant print out the second food. what should i do to print out 2 food as there are in 2 rows in same table

Comment: so the reason why that happens is that on your where clause you are specifying 2 conditions Merchant_Name = Merchant_N AND 
Merchant.Merchant_ID = Food.Merchant_ID; it might be here that only one of the 2 foods on your table is matching this condition, for all the foods to return use a left outer join where your left table is the foods table and the table right is your merchant table

Comment: ```                                                                                                                           Insert into Food values(200,1000,'Cheesy Wedges(L)',6.49);
Insert into Food values(201,1000,'Loaded Potato Bowl',6.99);
```                                                                                                                                  
 this is the code where i insert the data to Food table, as the 1000 is the Food.Merchant_ID,shouldn't be print out both food as both also have the same Food.Merchant_ID which is 1000?

Comment: and the Merchant_Name and Merchant_N is I assume 'KFC'

Comment: Merchant_Name is the variable inside my Merchant data while Merchant_N is the parameter, i need to find out the Merchant_ID which is 1000 so i need these condition Merchant_Name = Merchant_N AND Merchant.Merchant_ID = Food.Merchant_ID; is it?

Comment: try changing your proc to this CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE showMenu(Merchant_N IN Varchar2)
AS 
Food_Name Varchar2(30) := null;
BEGIN
SELECT Food_Name 
INTO Food_Name
From Food 
left outer join Merchant 
on 
Merchant.Merchant_ID = Food.Merchant_ID;
Where Merchant_Name = Merchant_N AND 
dbms_output.enable; 
dbms_output.put_line('The food is');
dbms_output.put_line(Food_Name);
END;

EXEC showMenu(‘KFC’)

Comment: Insert into Merchant values(1000,100,'KFC','Elon Musk','010-9725364');
 this is the data inside the Merchant table

Comment: Also, the reason you need to set servout on is because pl/sql has no mechanism for communicating directly with the client.  dbms_output.put_line simply writes to a buffer.  It is up to the client to choose to process that buffer or ignore it.  'set serverout on' directs sqlplus to process the buffer.  Some clients have no mechanism for this, and so it is poor practice to use dbms_output for production code.  It is fine for debugging and demo purposes.